# Spring MVC, best practices controller logic for visitors and authenticated members

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a website where loggedin members can organize activities and subscribe to other people's activities. For now, I have defined some different controllers divided along business objects. 
So there is a ActivityController for creating, modifying, subscribing to activities and view your own subscribed activities as well as the current activity agenda. And a MemberController for viewing member information and edit your own profile.

Most actions are for the logged in member only. But there are some actions for the not logged in visitor, like sign up, sign in and some general information about the website.
Also, I would like to make the visitor able to see the activity agenda, but hiding some details like the exact time and location of the activities.

And that makes my current approach a bit problematic. Actions cannot be divided strictly between visitors and members anymore. For example, the activity agenda is visible for both visitors and members, though loggedin members see more details. 
There are still actions which are for member only, like viewing activity details, organizing activities and subscribing to them. For these actions, I want to redirect to the login page when the url is invoked by a not loggedin visitor, using a HandlerInterceptor.

Does it make sense to makes separate controllers  for visitor only actions, member only actions and actions which are for visitors and members (but with slightly different effects). Or should we divide the controller according to business objects and handle the redirection to login page on URL base in the SecurityInterceptor path patterns as defined in the  MVC configuration file:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new SecurityInterceptor())
        .addPathPatterns("/activities/**", ...);
}
```

Or should   we define completely different actions (with different URL patterns) for "member only" actions on one hand, always redirecting to the login page when if no login session is present, and actions which are also accessible for unauthenticaed users on the other hand?
I hope I make my point clear, I realize it is not really a technical question but more a design issue and hope for some hints!

Answer (score 0):

I handle a similar situation by putting the methods in the controllers that make sense logically, however that may be in your situation, but then add `@PreAuthorize` annotations to any methods that need to be restricted. In your case, something like the following:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('MEMBER')")
@RequestMapping("/members")
public String membersOnly() {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

This way, if a visitor tried to access the method, they cannot, and are sent to the login page instead.

In the case of methods that can be accessed by both, that is solved by simply allowing both in your security annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('MEMBER', 'VISITOR')")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand tat those are Spring Security annotations which I do not use right now. It appears to have a pretty steep learning curve but is maybe worth considering.  And for the methods accessible by both, can you handle a (slightly) different implementation for the different roles?

Comment: Yes, within the shared method, you could just wrap the member (or visitor) specific content in something like `if(request.isUserInRole("MEMBER"))`